# In what region is $|z^2 + 9|<1$ for complex $z$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

In what region is $|z^2 + 9|<1$  for complex $z$?

I wrote this inequality $|z - 3i||z + 3i|<1$.

So I know they are asking for the set of points the product of whose distances from $3i$ and $-3i$ is less than 1.

I'm thinking a good idea is to first find the set of points the product of whose distances from $3i$ and $-3i$ equals 1.

I believe I've found these points lying on the imaginary axis : $\sqrt8i, -\sqrt8i, \sqrt10i, -\sqrt10i$.

But no idea how to find the others, and more generaly, no idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: $|z- a|$ is the distance from $z$ to $a$, so $|z+a|$ is the distance from $z$ to $-a$. Does this help?

Comment: I already knew this, still not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @trynalearn That can be written in cartesian as $\,(x^2-y^2 + 9)^2 + 4 x^2y^2 \lt 1\,$. The boundary is a [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_plane_curve) [curve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2-y%5E2+%2B+9)%5E2+%2B+4+x%5E2y%5E2+%3D+1), not obviously simplifiable. What kind of solution do you expect to find, and what's the wider context?

Comment: It's called a [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval).

Comment: It looks like [two ovals](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E2-y%5E2%2B9)%5E2%2B4x%5E2y%5E2%3D1&t=crmtb01) doesn't it?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes it does, but it's referred to as a (i.e., one) Cassini oval.

Comment: I think they are circles!

Comment: @David Thanks.  I see it in the Wikipedia article now.  Just my ignorance showing.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$1>|z^2+9|\geq|z|^2-9\to |z|^2<10$$
and
$$1>|z^2+9|\geq9-|z|^2\to |z|^2>8$$
then the desired area lies in $2\sqrt{2}<|z|<\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Don't we also need to show the reverse implication?

Comment: Geometric consideration shows the area is $|z\pm3i|=r$ with $r\sim\sqrt{10}-3$.

Answer (score 1):

If $z=x+iy$, then $z^2=(x^2-y^2)+2xyi$.  Now $\lvert z^2+9\rvert\lt1$ translates to $\lvert (x^2-y^2+9)+2xyi\rvert\lt1\implies (x^2-y^2+9)^2+(2xy)^2\lt1\implies x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4+18x^2-18y^2+y^4+81+4x^2y^2\lt1\implies x^4+y^4+18x^2-18y^2+81+2x^2y^2\lt1 $

@dxiv points out that this is the region enclosed by a quartic curve...  or, a Cassini Oval, according to @David...
@user 108128 has shown that the region lies in a certain annulus...

Comment: David has only shown that the region is a subset of that annulus, didn't he?

Comment: I believe so...

Comment: David hasn't shown anything, that was @user108128 :)

Comment: @David Ah haha :)

Comment: How would a mortal such as myself attempt to sketch this region? Or the boundary curve for that matter.

Comment: @trynalearn It consists of two disconnected loops, with foci at $\pm3i$...

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, there are two regions, roughly centred on $3i$ and $-3i$ respectively. Suppose $x + iy$ lies on the boundary of the first region. Then
$$(x + iy)^2 = -9 + e^i\theta$$
for some $\theta$ ($0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi$). Equate real and imaginary parts:
$$\cos\theta = x^2 - y^2 + 9,\quad\sin\theta = 2xy.$$
Multiply the first by $4y^2$ and substitute for $(2xy)^2$ from the second:
$$4y^4 + 4(\cos\theta - 9)y^2 -\sin^2\theta = 0,$$
a quadratic in $y^2$. Taking the positive root, and recalling that $y$ is roughly $3$ rather than $-3$, we get
$$y = \sqrt{9 - \cos\theta + \sqrt{82 - 18\cos\theta}\over2}.$$
From $\sin\theta\ = 2xy$ above we get
$$x = {\rm sgn}(\sin\theta)\sqrt{-9 + \cos\theta + \sqrt{82 - 18\cos\theta}\over2}.$$
If we put $u = \cos(\theta/2)$ then the boundary is parametrized by
$$x = {\rm sgn}(u)\sqrt{-5 + u^2 + \sqrt{25 - 9u^2}},\quad y=\sqrt{5 - u^2 + \sqrt{25 - 9u^2}}$$
for $-1 \le u \le 1$ (where $u = \pm1$ give the same point $(0, \sqrt8)$).